# chain rule for weak derivatives

Tags: sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives, elliptic-equations

First I apologise for not writing properly, but I'm using a cell phone.

We know that having a Sobolev function $u$, if we have a good enough function $f$, then $f\circ u$ is Sobolev and the chain rule holds. It is easy to prove this if for example $f$ is pointwise $\mathcal{C}^1$ with bounded derivative and the set is bounded. I'm reading for elliptic PDE Analysis and there is a lemma where we know that $f\circ u$ is Sobolev, $u$ is an $H^1$ solution to an elliptic PDE, but for $f$ we only know that it is locally Lipschitz and convex, however the writer claims that the chain rule holds and this is what I don't see. I have used mollifiers and several techniques but I cannot prove this without having a bound on the derivative of $f$. Maybe I should use convexity somehow, but I don't know how. Can anyone help?

Comment: Some control on $f$ at infinity would be needed, I think. Can you give a precise reference to the claim?

Comment: I don't believe this is true. Maybe you have more information of $u$ and domain $\Omega$? For example, $\Omega$ is bounded and somehow by embedding you have $u$ is actually $L^\infty$. I don't think convex will help here, just take $x^2$ and it blow up at infinity.

Comment: Well, thank you answering guys. The lemma is stated exactly as I wrote it here. However, later in the notes it is used only with functions u with compact image in the domain of f, therefore we have a unique lipschitz constant and there is no problem.

Comment: Cool. Nice to know it.